# How to save files in linux centos

Tags: linux, centos

when i'm edit a file using
`sudo -e [name of file]` and then i want to save and close, how to do that?

For example, when it's nano..i press ctrl key and x to save and close.
please, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tools to edit files on Centos are *vi* and *vim*. Open the desired file with one of those, press **i** to edit, press **ESC** to exit edit mode and press **ZZ** (capital Zs) to save.
Hope this helps.